# What is the look and feel of Violet UML Editor

Tags: java, look-and-feel

I was wondering what was the look and feel used in the java application 
[Violet UML Editor](http://violet.sourceforge.net/). It seem it name is "Blue Vista" but I can't find it on google.

Pictures :

[image: imgur.com/5AEbb.png]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the question - it led me to find Violet. I've been thinking about looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Violet's [VistaBlueTheme](http://violet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/violet/VioletFramework/src/main/java/com/horstmann/violet/framework/theme/VistaBlueTheme.java?revision=1.1&view=markup) is a custom [theme](http://violet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/violet/VioletFramework/src/main/java/com/horstmann/violet/framework/theme/) based on  `com.pagosoft.plaf.PgsLookAndFeel` and `com.pagosoft.plaf.themes.VistaTheme` from the 
[**PgsLookAndFeel**](http://pagosoft.com/products/pgslookandfeel/index.html) (plus some widgets from [L2FProd.com](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/index.php)).

Comment: Tanks for editing my post. I couldn't add the picture directy because I was a new user. 

And tanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find out looking at the source code.

You can find it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/

Update with your findings.